# python opengl with glfw mouse wheel zoom too further.the camera cover data object

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl

i have two questions.

1. I's normal in most cases when i use mouse wheel to zoom in.Once I zoom in to a certain level,it will zoom in farther.(near the center)
2. When the object(line or triangle) through the screan,some part of the object will be covered.

as shown below
[image: normal data]
[image: when scrool the mouse once,zoom in too further and some part of data are covered]

Here's my code.I don't know how should i change it.
Mouse scroll function: scroll_callback
the camera cover data: how to set the camera boundary

```
from math import pi
from threading import Thread

import glfw
import glm
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram

gl_shape = {'lines': GL_LINES, 'line_strip': GL_LINE_STRIP, 'triangles': GL_TRIANGLES,
            'triangle_strip': GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP}
gl_draw = {'seldom': GL_STATIC_DRAW, 'often': GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, 'always': GL_STREAM_DRAW}


class MyOpenGL(Thread):
    instances = {}
    first_instance = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance not in cls.instances:
            cls.instances[instance] = super().__new__(cls)
            cls.first_instance[instance] = True  # 判断是否是第一次创建
        return cls.instances[instance]

    def __init__(self, title: str = 'opengl_title', instance: str = None, draw_axis=True, axis_len=1.0):
        super().__init__()
        if not self.__class__.first_instance.get(instance):  # 判断是否是第一次创建
            return
        self.__class__.first_instance[instance] = False

        self.vertex_src = """
# version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_color;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
out vec3 v_color;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_color = a_color;
}
"""  # vec4(a_position, 1); 1指物体大小，越大越小
        self.fragment_src = """
# version 330
in vec3 v_color;
out vec4 out_color;
void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);   
}
"""
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        self.eye = glm.vec3(0, 0, 3)  # 眼睛的位置（默认z轴的正方向）
        self.target = glm.vec3(0, 0, 0)  # 瞄准方向的参考点（默认在坐标原点）
        self.up = glm.vec3(0, 1, 0)  # 定义对观察者而言的上方（默认y轴的正方向）
        self.near = 0.1
        self.far = 100
        self.radians = glm.radians(45)
        self.projection = glm.perspective(self.radians, self.width / self.height, self.near, self.far)
        self.view = glm.lookAt(self.eye, self.target, self.up)
        self.pan_start = None
        self.orbit_start = None
        self.pivot_world = None
        self.draw_axis = draw_axis
        self.axis_len = axis_len

        self.title = title
        self.window = None
        self.program = None
        self.vao = {}
        self.to_bind_data = {}
        self.vao_draw_args = {}
        self.vao_index = 1
        self.data_change = False

    def glfw_init(self, title='opengl_title'):
        if not glfw.init():
            print("Cannot initialize GLFW")
            exit()
        self.window = glfw.create_window(self.width, self.height, title, None, None)
        if not self.window:
            glfw.terminate()
        glfw.make_context_current(self.window)

    def draw_axis_func(self, length=1.0):
        axis = np.array([
            length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, -length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, -length, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        ], np.float32)
        self.vao['default_axis'] = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.vao_draw_args['default_axis'] = glDrawArrays, (GL_LINES, 0, int(len(axis) / 6))
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao['default_axis'])
        vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, axis.nbytes, axis, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)  # 准备设置glsl。即vertex_src中的layout(location = 0)的属性
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, axis.itemsize * 6, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)  # 准备设置glsl。即vertex_src中的layout(location = 1)的属性
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, axis.itemsize * 6, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

    def depth(self, x, y):
        depth_buffer = glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
        depth_ = float(depth_buffer[0][0])
        if depth_ == 1:
            pt_drag = glm.vec3(0, 0, 0)
            clip_pos = self.projection * self.view * glm.vec4(pt_drag, 1)
            ndc_pos = glm.vec3(clip_pos) / clip_pos.w
            if -1 < ndc_pos.z < 1:
                depth_ = ndc_pos.z * 0.5 + 0.5
        return depth_

    # def update_fps_counter(self):
    #     """    显示帧率        update_fps_counter(window)"""
    #     self.previous_seconds = self.__dict__.get('previous_seconds') or 0
    #     self.fps = self.__dict__.get('previous_seconds') or 0
    #     self.frame_count = self.__dict__.get('previous_seconds') or 0
    #     current_seconds = glfw.get_time()
    #     elapsed_seconds = current_seconds - self.previous_seconds
    #     if elapsed_seconds > 0.25:
    #         self.previous_seconds = current_seconds
    #         self.fps = self.frame_count / elapsed_seconds
    #         print(self.fps)
    #         self.frame_count = 0
    #     self.frame_count += 1

    def window_size_callback(self, window, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        # 旋转速度随窗口变化而变化
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.projection = glm.perspective(self.radians, width / height, self.near, self.far)

    def mouse_button_callback(self, window, button, action, mods):
        x_pos, y_pos = glfw.get_cursor_pos(window)
        y_pos = self.height - y_pos
        if button == glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT and action == glfw.PRESS:
            self.pan_start = glm.vec3(x_pos, y_pos, self.depth(x_pos, y_pos))
        if button == glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and action == glfw.PRESS:
            self.orbit_start = glm.vec3(x_pos, y_pos, self.depth(x_pos, y_pos))
            self.pivot_world = glm.vec3(0, 0, 0)

    def cursor_pos_callback(self, window, x_pos, y_pos):
        y_pos = self.height - y_pos
        # get view matrix and  viewport rectangle
        view, inv_view = self.view, glm.inverse(self.view)
        view_rect = glm.vec4(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        if glfw.get_mouse_button(window, glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) == glfw.PRESS:
            # get drag start and end
            wnd_from = self.pan_start
            wnd_to = glm.vec3(x_pos, y_pos, self.pan_start[2])
            self.pan_start = wnd_to

            # get projection and window matrix
            inv_proj = glm.inverse(self.projection)
            inv_wnd = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), glm.vec3(-1, -1, -1))
            inv_wnd = glm.scale(inv_wnd, glm.vec3(2 / view_rect[2], 2 / view_rect[3], 2))
            inv_wnd = glm.translate(inv_wnd, glm.vec3(view_rect[0], view_rect[1], 0))

            # calculate drag start and world coordinates
            pt_h_world = [inv_view * inv_proj * inv_wnd * glm.vec4(*pt, 1) for pt in [wnd_from, wnd_to]]
            pt_world = [glm.vec3(pt_h) / pt_h.w for pt_h in pt_h_world]

            # calculate drag world translation
            world_vec = pt_world[1] - pt_world[0]

            # translate view position and update view matrix
            inv_view = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), world_vec * -1) * inv_view
            view = glm.inverse(inv_view)
        elif glfw.get_mouse_button(window, glfw.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == glfw.PRESS:
            # get the drag start and end
            wnd_from = self.orbit_start
            wnd_to = glm.vec3(x_pos, y_pos, self.orbit_start[2])
            self.orbit_start = wnd_to

            # calculate the pivot, rotation axis and angle
            pivot_view = glm.vec3(view * glm.vec4(*self.pivot_world, 1))
            orbit_dir = wnd_to - wnd_from

            # get the projection of the up vector to the view port
            # TODO

            # calculate the rotation components for the rotation around the view space x axis and the world up vector
            orbit_dir_x = glm.vec2(0, 1)
            orbit_vec_x = glm.vec2(0, orbit_dir.y)
            orbit_dir_up = glm.vec2(1, 0)
            orbit_vec_up = glm.vec2(orbit_dir.x, 0)

            # calculate the rotation matrix around the view space x axis through the pivot
            rot_pivot_x = glm.mat4(1)
            if glm.length(orbit_vec_x) > 0.5:
                axis_x = glm.vec3(-1, 0, 0)
                angle_x = glm.dot(orbit_dir_x, glm.vec2(orbit_vec_x.x / (view_rect[2] - view_rect[0]),
                                                        orbit_vec_x.y / (view_rect[3] - view_rect[1]))) * pi
                rot_mat_x = glm.rotate(glm.mat4(1), angle_x, axis_x)
                rot_pivot_x = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), pivot_view) * rot_mat_x * glm.translate(glm.mat4(1),
                                                                                                 -pivot_view)
            # calculate the rotation matrix around the world space up vector through the pivot
            rot_pivot_up = glm.mat4(1)
            if glm.length(orbit_vec_up) > 0.5:
                axis_up = glm.vec3(0, 0, 1)
                angle_up = glm.dot(orbit_dir_up, glm.vec2(
                    orbit_vec_up.x / (view_rect[2] - view_rect[0]),
                    orbit_vec_up.y / (view_rect[3] - view_rect[1]))) * pi
                rot_mat_up = glm.rotate(glm.mat4(1), angle_up, axis_up)
                rot_pivot_up = glm.translate(
                    glm.mat4(1), self.pivot_world) * rot_mat_up * glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), -self.pivot_world)
            # transform and update view matrix
            view = rot_pivot_x * view * rot_pivot_up

        self.view = view

    def scroll_callback(self, window, x_offset, y_offset):
        x, y = glfw.get_cursor_pos(window)
        y = self.height - y
        view_rect = glm.vec4(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        # get view, projection and window matrix
        proj, inv_proj = self.projection, glm.inverse(self.projection)
        view, inv_view = self.view, glm.inverse(self.view)
        inv_wnd = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), glm.vec3(-1, -1, -1))
        inv_wnd = glm.scale(inv_wnd, glm.vec3(2 / view_rect[2], 2 / view_rect[3], 2))
        inv_wnd = glm.translate(inv_wnd, glm.vec3(view_rect[0], view_rect[1], 0))
        wnd = glm.inverse(inv_wnd)

        # get world space position on view ray
        pt_wnd = glm.vec3(x, y, 1.0)
        # pt_world  = glm.unProject(pt_wnd, view, proj, vp_rect)
        pt_h_world = inv_view * inv_proj * inv_wnd * glm.vec4(*pt_wnd, 1)
        pt_world = glm.vec3(pt_h_world) / pt_h_world.w

        # get view position
        eye = glm.vec3(inv_view[3])

        # get "zoom" direction and amount
        ray_cursor = glm.normalize(pt_world - eye)

        # translate view position and update view matrix
        inv_view = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), ray_cursor * y_offset) * inv_view

        # return new view matrix
        self.view = glm.inverse(inv_view)

    def set_data(self, data, data_name=None, frequency=None, shape=None, indices=None):
        if data_name is None:
            data_name = self.vao_index
            self.vao_index += 1
            # print(data_name)
        self.to_bind_data[data_name] = (data, frequency, shape, indices)
        return data_name

    def bind_data(self):
        if not self.to_bind_data:
            return
        for data_name in list(self.to_bind_data.keys()):
            self.vao[data_name] = glGenVertexArrays(1)
            data, frequency, shape, indices = self.to_bind_data[data_name]
            glBindVertexArray(self.vao[data_name])
            vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sum(len(i) for i in data) * 4, None, gl_draw.get(frequency, GL_STATIC_DRAW))
            offset = 0
            for d in data:
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, d.nbytes, d)
                offset += d.nbytes
            if indices is not None:
                ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
                length = sum(len(i) for i in indices) * 4
                glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, length, None, gl_draw.get(frequency, GL_STATIC_DRAW))
                offset = 0
                for i, sub_arr in enumerate(indices):
                    arr = (ctypes.c_uint32 * sub_arr.nbytes)(*(sub_arr + 4 * i))
                    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sub_arr.nbytes, arr)
                    offset += sub_arr.nbytes
                prop = glDrawElements, (gl_shape.get(shape, GL_LINE_STRIP), length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
            else:
                # 最后一个参数为画几个点
                prop = glDrawArrays, (gl_shape.get(shape, GL_LINE_STRIP), 0, sum(int(len(d) / 6) for d in data))

            self.vao_draw_args[data_name] = prop
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)  # 准备设置glsl。即vertex_src中的layout(location = 0)的属性
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 6, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)  # 准备设置glsl。即vertex_src中的layout(location = 1)的属性
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 6, ctypes.c_void_p(12))  # 3*arr.itemsize
            self.to_bind_data.pop(data_name)

    def draw_data(self):
        for n in self.vao:
            glBindVertexArray(self.vao[n])
            self.vao_draw_args[n][0](*self.vao_draw_args[n][1])
            # print(self.vao_draw_args[n][0],self.vao_draw_args[n][1])

    def run(self):
        self.glfw_init(self.title)
        if self.draw_axis:
            self.draw_axis_func(self.axis_len)
        glfw.set_window_size_callback(self.window, self.window_size_callback)
        glfw.set_mouse_button_callback(self.window, self.mouse_button_callback)
        glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(self.window, self.cursor_pos_callback)
        glfw.set_scroll_callback(self.window, self.scroll_callback)

        self.program = compileProgram(compileShader(self.vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                      compileShader(self.fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        # 设置模型坐标,和glUniformMatrix4fv不能写成一行，写成一行会无法展示，可能是因为用的指针地址
        mat = glm.mat4()
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'model'), 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(mat))

        while not glfw.window_should_close(self.window):
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'projection'), 1, GL_FALSE,
                               glm.value_ptr(self.projection))
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'view'), 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(self.view))
            glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)  # 在glClear后会显示为glClearColor中的颜色
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            self.bind_data()
            self.draw_data()

            glfw.poll_events()
            glfw.swap_buffers(self.window)
        glfw.terminate()
        print('glfw close')


result = [
    np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.4, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32),
    np.array([-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.5, -0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              -0.4, -0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.4, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32),
    np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
              0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)
]
ins = [np.array([2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint32), np.array([2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint32),
       np.array([2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint32)]

line = [
    np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
]

ogl = MyOpenGL()
ogl.start()

ogl.set_data(result, data_name=f'j', frequency='always', shape='triangles', indices=ins)
ogl.set_data(line, data_name=f'l', frequency='always')
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes,there's a little space between  Viewing frustum and the object. Are there any method to clear the space

Comment: @Rabbid76  I want to know how to reduce the zoom level or limit the maximum degree of amplification(like [three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines))